# How to set value for hidden field when a link clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to set value for hidden field(sub_catid) when a link clicked. My source codes as below.

**Hidden Input Field**

```
<input type="hidden" name="sub_catid" value="" id="sub_catid">
```

**a link**

```
<a href="#" data-subcat="3" class="sub-cat-id">Sub Category Name</a>
```

Comment: Can you include what you have tried at Question?

Comment: Your question contains the answer. You want to set some value _onclick_ of a link, then have an onclick function for that link that sets the value for the hidden field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function func(btnId){
    document.getElementById('sub_catid').value = document.getElementById(btnId).getAttribute('data-subcat');
    //testing new value
    alert(document.getElementById('sub_catid').value);
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="sub_catid" value="" id="sub_catid">
a link
<a id="button" href="#" data-subcat="3" class="sub-cat-id" onclick="func(this.id)">Sub Category Name</a>
```

Comment: I want to pass that data-subcat="3" value to hidden field. How can i do that?

Comment: Thank you very much for your big support. Now it's working properly.